# How to share image with share package in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Somewhere on stack i found an answer about how to share image trough share package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share#-readme-tab-), and someone said to convert Bytes to base64 encoding and then share this string like that:

```
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  String bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);

  await Share.share(bs64).then((response){
   Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      setState(() {
        loadingShare = false;
        loadingShareIndex = -1;
      });
    });
  });`
```

I excpected to show an image but only shows long string to share...